# Detect string in a string using Windows Batch script to generate domain name and paths from file paths

Tags: batch-file

I have a Windows Explorer Context Menu item that will be calling a batch file and passing to it the file path of the file the context menu is shown on like this:

```
G:\htdocs\Labs\javascript\socialbuttons\socialable.html
```

What I need to do is detect if the file path is in my dev servers **projects** folder or in my **labs** folder.

If it is in my projects folder then I need to extract the domain name from the file path and store it in a variable with the remainder of the file path appended to it.

If it is in my labs folder it will just need to remove X number of characters from the string and store the remainder in a variable.

I know almost nothing of Batch scripting so I am trying to piece this together.

To detect if it is in my projects folder I think this will do the job...

So given this file path passed to the script...

```
G:\htdocs\projects\webdevapp\app\folder\file.php
```

then this code

```
IF "%variable:~0,18%"=="G:\htdocs\projects"
```

would see that this is a projects file.

It would then need to grab this part from the string `webdevapp` and add `http://` to the start of it and `.dev` to the end of it.   Next it would need to append the remaining file path `\app\folder\file.php` to it.

Next it would need to replace the `\`s with `/`s

The resulting string would be:

```
http://webdevapp.dev/app/folder/file.php
```

---

Now if the file path does not have the projects path in it and is a labs folder then it just needs to turn this:

```
G:\htdocs\Labs\javascript\socialbuttons\socialable.html
```

into this:

```
http://localhost/Labs/javascript/socialbuttons/socialable.html
```

---

I can then take the new string and open in a browser with this:

```
start chrome.exe domain_variable_here
```

---

Based on what I have, can anyone help with the next step or to get this working?

Comment: Yes, of course! Right click on a folder, select New > Text Document and change the name and extension to `test.bat`. Then, open it and start typing the commands; I suggest `@echo off` in the first line. When the file is complete, open a cmd.exe session, `cd` to the directory where the `test.bat` file is and execute it entering its name. _After that_ you may edit your question, delete all non-related text and describe the specifications in a more concise way,  _post your code_ and ask specific questions about it...

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "xchars=5"
set "pathtf=your path here"
echo %pathtf% | find "labs"
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
set "pathtf=!pathtf:~0,-%xchars%!"
goto :eof
)
echo %pathtf% | find "projects"
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
set "pathtf=%pathtf:\=/%"
set "pathtf=%pathtf:G:\htdocs\projects\webdevapp=http://webdevapp.dev%"
)
echo %pathtf%
```

the result will be stored in %pathtf%

Comment: The command `set "pathtf=%pathtf:~0,-%xchars%%"` won't work, you need either `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` and use `set "pathtf=!pathtf:~0,-%xchars%!"` or use a pseudo call and double the outer percent signs. `call set "pathtf=%%pathtf:~0,-%xchars%%%"`